# All my static files in Django are not found, but findstatic finds them

Tags: django, python-3.x, apache, ubuntu-16.04, mod-wsgi

I am developing a Django site on an Ubuntu 16.04 LVM using Apache and mod_wgsi. When I try to load one of my pages, all the static files give a 404 not found error. I believe I have my settings set correctly because

> python3 manage.py findstatic

is able to find the files and running the development server with DEBUG=off and the --insecure flag, It still works correctly. Does this mean it is an issue with apache?

Here are my static file settings:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
        #'/home/matt/jukebox/bin/jukebox/static/'

)
```

Does anybody know what could be wrong? The files were being served previously, but after updating my server and the code for the site, it stopped serving.

Thank You

Comment: How have you configured Apache to serve those files?

Comment: Does it need special configuration? What's really throwing me off is that it was serving them before I updated my server.. I wouldn't imagine updating would reset my previous configuration.

Comment: Django docs on serving static files with mod_wsgi can be found at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#serving-files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this to my apache config file fixed the issue:

```
Alias /static /home/user/myproject/static
<Directory /home/user/myproject/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I found the answer here:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-apache-and-mod_wsgi-on-ubuntu-14-04

Still not sure why it had been working previously without these settings, but hopefully this answer can help someone.